# Fortran bindings to Vulkan API

Tags: fortran, vulkan

Is there some place I could get Fortran bindings to Vulkan?
Or do I have to manually write signatures of all C functions?

Comment: As to your first question - well that's off-topic here.  As for your second - well if your exhaustive searches of the internet haven't answered your first, best roll up your sleeves, put on a large pot of coffee, and roll out your favourite IDE ...

Comment: You can try to adapt the scripts that vmagnin uses for GTK Fortran.

Comment: - You can either write Fortran / C interfaces by hand using iso_c_binding
- or try to use an automatic wrapper like https://github.com/swig-fortran (but it's for C++) or https://github.com/eliben/pycparser
- The scripts in gtk-fortran were written with only GTK in focus and may be more or less difficult to adapt to another library.

Comment: You can probably try adapting C++ bindings generator for Fortran output: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/blob/master/VulkanHppGenerator.cpp